# Help with setup of a USB DVB TV tuner (Hauppauge WinTV-SoloHD) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mate, dvb-t

I will start off by saying that I've read and followed these instructions by Hauppauge here: https://www.hauppauge.com/pages/support/support_linux.html

Got as far as typing the command to install the Linux-firmware-huppauge.

I will add that I'm not good at understanding terminal commands. They all did what the instructions and video intended them to do though, but reading what they say means nothing to me.

It is continuing on form this instruction that I'm stuck:

"You can now connect your Hauppauge WinTV TV tuner to your computer and it should be available for use by your Linux TV watching application."

But there are obviously a whole load more steps involved in the program you are going to be using, and I don't know which one is best or how to set them up.

Back when I had Ubuntu 18.04, I had it set up with VLC (xine worked too), but can't remember how that was done. VLC seems to be getting more and more unreliable since each ubuntu update. The last time it seemed stable for me was back in 16.04, so would probably prefer another program.

Now I have done all the steps in this tutorial, it is what I do next that I'm stuck on. I've tried following instructions for VLC, Kaffeine and one or two others, but either they are to complex for me to be doing it right, or they are not working.

What I'm wanting on this is just the UK's freeview channels. I only bought this TV tuner relatively recently and it was a lot more expensive than a budget freeview box, but I wanted it so I can watch freeview on my computer and it is a shame I can't yet work out a way to get a program to work with it.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find and install TVHeadend and follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for getting back even after this much time has gone by. I haven't been using it at all because of the issues. I'm now on 22.04 using MATE. I still however haven;t been able to find a program that supports it. https://tvheadend.org/boards/4/topics/47932   Following the instructions here, I get this in the terminal after the first step: "E: Package 'libavresample-dev' has no installation candidate"

Comment: @LannyLuttrell This is not an answer wrt the site rules here, you need to copy the method into your answer and cite a page, eg the tvheadend.org install page. You need to be sure that it works for the questioner's hardware too. If you're not sure then you should post it as a comment until they confirmt the solution works. Cheers.

Comment: FWIW you can get [libavresample-dev at ubuntuupdates.org](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?q=libavresample-dev).